# Excel autofill not working as expected

Tags: microsoft-excel, autocomplete, microsoft-excel-2013

I am using MS Excel 2013. I have two columns - `Year` and `Quarter` like this:

```
2009    1
2009    2
2009    3
2009    4
2010    1
2010    2
2010    3
2010    4
2011    1
2011    2
2011    3
2011    4
2012    1
2012    2
2012    3
2012    4
2013    1
```

I would expect that if I select the two columns and drag the selection down I would have `2013 2`, `2013 3` and so fort. Instead I get:

1) If no formatting is applied to the cells:

```
2012.852941 2.588235294
2013.098039 2.607843137
2013.343137 2.62745098
2013.588235 2.647058824
2013.833333 2.666666667
2014.078431 2.68627451
2014.323529 2.705882353
```

2) If both columns are formatted as numbers:

```
2013    3
2013    3
2013    3
2014    3
2014    3
2014    3
```

In the second scenario at least the `Year` column is populated as expected, but not the `Quarter` column. What should I do to get autofill to work as expected?

Comment: The problem is repeatable in Excel 2003. I believe that autocomplete can't figure out the pattern and as such, is trying to figure out a series. However, there seems to be an option to just copy the results.

Comment: Yes, currently I am using the workaround with copying but it seems odd that such a simple pattern is not recognizable by Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer clearly explains why. My solution is a bit simpler though.

1. Fill the first four cells with 2010 manually
2. then make the next Cell reference the first 2010 Cell ( A5:  =A1+1 )
3. You can then drag this down as many as you need.

You can also get column two in a similar way. put in your first 1-2-3-and 4 then instead of setting

- B5:  =B1+1  Set B5:  =B1

Dragging it down results in

- B6:=B2
- B7:=B3
- and so on.

[image: Regular Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot with 'Show Formulas' Option Enabled]

Comment: Yeah, but the first column was never the problem, Excel recognizes this pattern when formatted as number. It's the second column that is giving me problems.

Comment: Do the same thing in the second column, just with 1,2,3, and 4 instead of 2010 four times

Comment: But 1, 2, 3 and 4 do not increment, they repeat.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain more fully. Basically just drop the +1 in the second column

Answer (score 3):

Well, I checked [Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-HP010342512.aspx?CTT=1#_Toc293583899) and what I said appears to be true. **Auto Fill** tries to fill the values according to a series that he can determine.

I graphed the points and it seems Excel is just doing a standard linear extrapolation.

[image: Graphing points]

If you link the first and last point in your defined series you would get roughly the same line as you got.

This is for the why. Now for the *how to solve*. Like I said, you can have the same effect with formulas.

You need to have 3 cells (maybe something else can be done with the new Table dialog in newer Excels), your two cells plus a "row number" cell.

The first cell is simply a cell containing the numbers of the rows, starting with 0. You can do that with Auto Fill. Now, for the second cell, have this formula:

```
= 2009 + TRUNC(A1/4;0)
```

What this does is to add a year whenever the left column has a number divisible by four. For the third:

```
= 1 + MOD(A1;4)
```

It works roughly on the same principle on the last. You can then drag the first row and Auto Fill will take it from there.

[image: End result]